# Object key value is different when dispatching and updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I had encountered a weird problem in javascript in ReactJS.

I had an object for example.

```
let obj = {key: "value_(category)", name: "objName"}

dispatch(actions.add(obj))
dispatch(actions.replace(obj))
```

in the reducer below, i add it and update the data in state and replace the same obj

```
const initialState = {
    data: []
};

const reducer = function (state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.Add:
            return { data: [...state, action.payload] }
        case Actions.Replace:
            return { data: state.data.map((chip) => { return chip.key === action.payload.key ? action.payload : chip }) };
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

The first dispatch does update the key with the correct value, which is value_(category), but on the second dispatch when i replace it, the key value become only "value".

Im expecting it to shows the same value, its weird because there is no change in value at all in between two dispatch.